# ReactJs development on docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker

How can i use docker container to develop Reactjs with docker on windows ?

So far I've been able to run my app, but livereload does not work.

App/structure

- build
- node_module
- public
- src
- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:5.11.0-slim

# Prepare app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

# Install dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install --silent

ADD . /usr/src/app/

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: "boilerplate"
    build: .
    environment:
      env_file: .env
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

Comment: You don't need the EXPOSE or ADD in your dockerfile since you have them in compose. What path is livereload watching?

Comment: Cool, I'll remove here :) I would like to monitor the /src

Comment: I've not used livereload but it looks like you need to set server.watch("/usr/src/app"), or alternatively use nodemon which drops in place of node and doesn't need any extra settings to do live reloading.

Comment: @ChrisTanner, with nodemon work for me :) but is a little slow :( thank very much for the answer

Comment: @BrunoReis how do you edit your code? do u use git?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## It's a known limitation for Windows (don't worry too much, there is a good workaround)

[This is a known limitation for Docker on Windows host](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30105#issuecomment-272267774). Here is what the [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#/inotify-on-shared-drives-does-not-work) says about the problem:

> **inotify on shared drives does not work**
>
> Currently, inotify does not work on Docker for Windows. This will
>   become evident, for example, when an application needs to read/write
>   to a container across a mounted drive. Instead of relying on
>   filesystem inotify, we recommend using polling features for your
>   framework or programming language.
>
> - Workaround for nodemon and Node.js - If you are using nodemon with    Node.js, try the fallback polling mode described here: [nodemon isn’t restarting node applications](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting)
> - Docker for Windows issue on GitHub - See the issue [Inotify on shared drives does not work](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/56#issuecomment-242135705)

---

## The workaround

However, the **workaround** is to use a polling mechanism:

- [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) - *A neat wrapper around node.js fs.watch / fs.watchFile / fsevents.*
- [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) - *Monitor for any changes in your node.js application and automatically restart the server - perfect for development*.
- [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions-poll) - *If watching does not work for you, try out polling option. Watching does not work with NFS and machines in VirtualBox.*
- etc ...

---

## Complete Docker & React setup

Just for your case I've started [react-create-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) in a Docker container and livereload feature works perfect. The gotcha is to [enable chokidar polling](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#troubleshooting) by creating .env configuration file.

Here are my configurations ([inspired by @haluvibe](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/982#issuecomment-273032553)):

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:6.9.4

# Prepare app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

# Install dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install --silent

ADD . /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: "boilerplate"
    build: .
    environment:
      env_file: .env
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

**.env**

```
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

### Scripts

- `docker-compose up -d` - Start your project and it will be available at http://localhost:3000.
- `docker-compose run --rm boilerplate /bin/bash` - Access your container.

Comment: Cool! and how exactly could one use vscode with git integration, while running said container e.g. inside centos7 vm? i could ssh into this vm and use mapped volume but that gonna ruin all container goodness.

Comment: This is out of my knowledge and experience. The answer is focused on running Docker locally on your OS, in order the developers to have a reproducible development environment.

Comment: I did the configuration with nodemon and CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING = true in .env and it worked, but my VM consumes 100% of the CPU to be analyzing the changes, any alternative solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

some times livereload dose not work when the app is running inside a container, If the project runs inside a virtual machine such as (a Vagrant provisioned) VirtualBox, create an .env file in your project directory if it doesn’t exist, and add CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true to it. This ensures that the next time you run npm start, the watcher uses the polling mode, as necessary inside a VM.